# What's the best choice of data structure to solve Timus Nr#1027?

Tags: c, data-structures

Could anybody tell me what's the best choice of data structure to solve the problem @ http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1027.

Copied here for reference.

**Problem**

> A text of a correct D++ program contains a symbol part, arithmetic
>   expressions and comments. Comments may appear everywhere and may
>   contain any symbols. A comment is always opened by a pair of symbols
>   (* and is closed by a pair of symbols * ) Each comment must be
>   closed. An arithmetic expression in D++ is always opened by "(", is
>   closed by ")" and may contain only symbols "=+-*/0123456789)(" and
>   "end of line" symbols. An arithmetic expression can't start with a
>   pair of symbols "(*". You may run across embedded brackets in an
>   arithmetic expression. In this case these brackets are to be balanced.
>   It means that "((1)))" as well as "(23))((+)" are not correct
>   arithmetic expressions. An arithmetic expression is correct if and
>   only if brackets placed correctly. At last, all the rest of the
>   program text (the result of rejection of all comments and arithmetic
>   expressions from the initial text of the program) may contain every
>   symbol excluding "(" and ")". We would like to especially notice that
>   the spaces are possible anywhere in a text of a program except when
>   appearing in arithmetic expressions.

Would hashing be useful ?

My approach is as below(there are still some bugs,concentrate on the DS part)

```
        #include <stdio.h>

        /* enable to get debug print statements */
        #define DEBUG_ENABLE 0
        #define INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER -1
        #define BUFSIZE 20

        char buf[BUFSIZE];/*buffer for ungetch*/
        int bufp=0;/*next free position in buf*/

        /*get a(possibly pushed-back)character*/
        int mygetch(FILE *infile)
        {
            return(bufp>0)? (buf[--bufp]): (getc(infile));
        }
        /*push a character back on input*/
        int ungetch(char c)
        {
            if(bufp >= BUFSIZE)
            {
                printf("ungetch:too many characters - increase the stack buffer size\n");
                return INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
            }
            else
            {
                buf[bufp++]=c;
                return 0;
            }
        }


        enum CharType
        {
            isAlphabet=0,
            isNumber,
            isSpace,
            isNewline,
            isOperator,
            isOpeningBrace,
            isClosingBrace,
            isStar,
            isOther
        };

        enum
        {
            False=0,
            True
        };

        /* return different codes for different types of input characters*/
        int getCharType(char ch)
        {
            if((ch>='A'&&ch<='Z') || (ch>='a'&&ch<='z'))
            {
                return isAlphabet;
            }
            else if(ch=='+'||ch=='-'||ch=='/'||ch=='=')
            {
                return isOperator;
            }
            else if(ch>='0'&& ch<='9')
            {
                return isNumber;
            }
            else if(ch=='*')
            {
                return isStar;
            }
            else if(ch=='(')
            {
                return isOpeningBrace;
            }
            else if(ch==')')
            {
                return isClosingBrace;
            }
            else if(ch==' ')
            {
                return isSpace;
            }
            else
            {
                return isOther;
            }
        }

        int parseInputFile(FILE *infile)
        {
            int ArthExpScanning = 0;
            int CmmntScanning = False;
            int ch,chtmp;

            while((ch=mygetch(infile))!=EOF)
            {
        #if DEBUG_ENABLE
                printf("%c",ch);
        #endif /*DEBUG_ENABLE*/
                switch(getCharType(ch))
                {
                /*Arithmetic Expression or possibly comment starts here*/
                case isOpeningBrace :
                    if((chtmp=mygetch(infile))!=EOF)
                    {
                     if(getCharType(chtmp)== isStar)
                     {
                         CmmntScanning = True;
        #if DEBUG_ENABLE
                         printf("\nCmmnt Scanning = True\n");
        #endif /*DEBUG_ENABLE*/
                     }
                     else if (CmmntScanning == False)
                     {
                         ArthExpScanning += 1;
        #if DEBUG_ENABLE
                         printf("\nArthExpScanning = %d\n",ArthExpScanning);
        #endif /*DEBUG_ENABLE*/
                         if(ungetch(chtmp) == INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
                         {
                             return (0);
                         }
                     }
                    }
                    break;
                    /*Arithmetic Expression possibly closes here */
                case isClosingBrace :
                    if(CmmntScanning == False)
                    {
                        ArthExpScanning -= 1;
        #if DEBUG_ENABLE
                        printf("\nArthExpScanning = %d\n",ArthExpScanning);
        #endif /*DEBUG_ENABLE*/
                    }
        #if DEBUG_ENABLE
                    if(ArthExpScanning < 0)
                    {
                        printf("\nerror here!!\n");
                    }
        #endif /*DEBUG_ENABLE*/
                    break;
                case isStar :
                    if((chtmp=mygetch(infile))!=EOF)
                    {
                        if((getCharType(chtmp)== isClosingBrace) && (CmmntScanning == True))
                     {
                         CmmntScanning = False;
        #if DEBUG_ENABLE
                         printf("\nCmmnt Scanning = False\n");
        #endif /*DEBUG_ENABLE*/
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         if(ungetch(chtmp) == INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
                         {
                             return (0);
                         }
                     }
                    }
                    break;

                case isSpace :
                    if((CmmntScanning == False) && (ArthExpScanning != 0))
                    {
                        /* Space not allowed while scanning arith exp */
        #if DEBUG_ENABLE
                        printf("NO \n");
        #endif /*DEBUG_ENABLE*/
                        return 0;
                    }
                    break;

                case isAlphabet :
                case isOperator :
                case isNumber :
                case isNewline :
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }

            if((ArthExpScanning == 0) && (CmmntScanning == False))
            {
                /* if there are no open braces and comments left after parsing the entire
                file return success*/
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }


        int main(int argc,char *argv[])
        {
            FILE *infile;

            if(argc != 2)
            {
                printf("Correct usage is : D++ExpParser inputfilename\n");
                return (-1);
            }
            if((infile = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL )
            {
                printf("Not able to open file : %f\n",argv[1]);
                return (-2);
            }
            if(parseInputFile(infile))
            {
             printf("YES\n");
            }
            else
            {
             printf("NO\n");
            }

            fclose(infile);
        }
```

Comment: Don't understand your question. Hashing in what context? Are you trying to keep a map of the symbols you will parse. Please explain your question clearly for anyone in the community to help you. Else your question might get down-voted. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the concept of hashing very well, So just spitballing here

Answer (score 0):

Hashing? No. Hint for your web search: this is a context-free grammar.

Comment: I have solved it by using a stack based approach. I have been told that better solution is possible. So just wondering..

Comment: Maybe you should present your solution, then it can be discussed.

Comment: Actually, I do not really understand your intention regarding the buffer. What do you do, if an arithmetic expression contains more than 20 characters?

Comment: BTW, the original problem uses (* ... *) for a comment. Is your modification a cut&past error?

Comment: To detect a comment '(*', I am reading two characters at a time and if the 2nd char is not a *, I am 'unreading' it using the buffer.

Comment: But then you would need a buffer of 2 at max. However, why putting back? If there no comments starts, the character *must* be part of an arithmetic expression; you could test this immediately.

Comment: you could have something like (((* and so on, so a bigger buffer is required

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of *recursion*?